# Signing votes so there is no way to determine user, but duplicate votes can be detected

Tags: cryptography, signing

I'm creating simple voting system, where main restrictions are:

- every person can vote only once
- each vote must be strictly anonymous
- system must be spreaded with covering situations where some of vote terminals won't have access to system network all the time so they will send votes periodically to main node.

By strictly anonymous I mean that there can't be anyone on earth with access to data who voted on what. There must be information about who already voted but can't be information what he voted.

This is simple to achieve by creating 2 buckets (database tables or something) of data, one with information about user that is voting, second with vote but no user data and allow inserting records only into both buckets at once, but only if particular user is not listed in first bucket already. That solution will work, but only if every node of the system can access main database all the time.

So there is second approach to sign each vote with some user data in way that each vote created by that user will have exact same sign but there will be no way to find user using that sign. I don't know how to create that kind of sign.

It can be based on something that only user have or something that only user knows, but it is not stored anywhere else and can be verified if it is legit. Some kind of certificate that won't reveal person it belongs to and can be invalidated if for example someone stole it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bozho [has written](http://techblog.bozho.net/why-all-the-fear-in-electronic-voting/) about electronic voting and it's well worth the read. In specific points you're trying to implement:

- allowing voters to vote only once - by using strong authentication method (i.e. multi-factor one) and maintaining a list of voters no-one can impersonate someone else and everyone gets only one chance to vote
- anonymizing votes - by using [blind signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature) users sign their vote which is then validated, counted and signed by independent party, after that the voter can submit their vote without their signature and therefore the vote is anonymous but still authenticated by the independent party
- semi-offline or batch submission of votes - I don't think that you can achieve this without compromising some of the previous points, you will end up putting trust in the ballot machine which can be compromised and submit fake votes or withhold them.

Independent party could be a distributed [block chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_chain_(database)) so that its truly independent, fault tolerant and eventually consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You could have users preregister at a specific location and are then only allowed to vote there (then, for each location, you could prefetch the list of all users allowed to vote there and only users on the list can vote). You could then proceed with the first approach.

This will of course not work (well, at all) if individual terminals talk directly to the main database and there isn't some intermediate node at each location for all the terminals at that location to talk to, which keeps track of users (I'm assuming, in general, there will be buildings with multiple voting booths / terminals).

There will still be some possibility of finding out what some users voted if you allow full access to the database in real time, because you can query the database before and after the vote and then just check what changed.

---

The second approach sounds like it requires a cryptographic perfect hash function, although I'm not sure such a thing exists. Related post - [Are cryptographic hash functions perfect hash functions?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8092/are-cryptographic-hash-functions-perfect-hash-functions) You could also try encryption, but knowing the algorithm and the key used will allow you to find the user who cast a vote, which is presumably not what you want.

Comment: Hash functions are good choice for me even if they are not perfect. If there will be just too much cost to crack it (there are some hash functions that have big computing cost, like `PBKDF2` and user tokens can be very, very long - I can store them on some removable media for each user) it won't be a problem.